# Editable table of data with JSON and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, twitter-bootstrap

For sports race results, I'm considering storing the results data as JSON in MySQL and would like to provide an easy interface for editing.

Is there anything that can take JSON produce a table, allow editing and update the JSON object..? which could then be passed back to PHP/MySQL.

The results data looks like:

```
Race    Grade     First     Second      Third       Time
350M    ‘A’       S. Samy   T. Harris   F. Cullin   31:72
450M    ‘B’       S. Bucket R. Jones    M. Jones    33:21
550M    'C'       R. Oly    S. Woods    P. Kircher
```

Comment: Why would you store it as JSON *in* MySQL?

Comment: I have to agree with the above. JSON should be used to communicate between the client and the server (or for other storage purposes such as local/session/cookies). MySQL should be organized for ease of use. Always imagine that someone else may take over your project. Would you want to deal with this?

Comment: All I need to do is store and retrieve. Seemed like a way to avoid extra work in setting up more complex table structures and queries, since the results data columns may vary.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) No sql database that stores things in JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store data in a relational database. Use functions or a framework utility to convert it to JSON format, then pass it to the webpage for javascript to consume and present to the user.

If a NoSQL database is suitable to your needs, they can store JSON documents and those documents are therefore emitted as JSON. [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org) is one example of these non-relational databases.